# Mysql minimum function

Tags: mysql, function, minimum

Is there a predefined MySQL function that returns minimum
 of its arguments' values (MINIMUM(1,16) -> 1)?

To be more specific, I have a time-on-site column in one of my mysql tables.
Every visitor polls my server every 30 sec making an update:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `lastUpdate` = NOW() WHERE `id` = ?;
```

but I'd like to update also timeOnSite column like this:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `timeOnSite` = (
`timeOnSite` + MINIMUM( 
                   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, lastUpdate, NOW()), 30
               )
 ),
`lastUpdate` = NOW() WHERE `id` = ?;
```

But the problem is that there are no such MINIMUM function, and I failed to find it in MySQL manuals.

Comment: the problem of finding answer in manuals raises from not very obvious keyword "least"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's because its called `LEAST()` to avoid confusion with the aggregate function `MIN()`.